# I want install python package and edit it

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

I installed a package locally using -e to install it in an editable mode, but when I make modifications they don't change.

I also installed a forked version of the package using -e and tried to make modifications and pushed them to my git repo but without success. Any suggestions why this doesn't work?

Comment: you can modify any package by going to its source code. it is not recommended tho because if one updated the package the modification would be overwritten.  For this reason, it would be a better idea to import the package and modify your own code.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. However, when I run the modified package, the changes are not made..

Comment: did you save the changes ?  if it is an imported module, save the changes,  exit the editor and then reopen the editor.  That would work (by ensuring that the module was not in the cache).